# Connection issue in MonkeyTalk IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, monkeytalk

I have installed monkey talk IDE to test the android apps and when I try to connect it to android emulator/tethred device, I got a warning

> An internal error occurred during: "MonkeyTalk". Error starting adb:
>   Error running adb: D:\android_sdk (aspire921) on
>   aspire764\platform-tools\adb.exe forward tcp:16862 tcp:16862 error:
>   device not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check the important thing that both the device and pc would be in same WI-FI Network, while trying to execute monkey-talk enabled apps. Now the connection was set successfully to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone must be on the **same** WiFi network as your PC. The app must be running on the phone in order to connect. About your recording issues, I would have to have more information.